# MariaDB show databases privilege

Tags: mysql, mariadb

running in the console `SHOW DATABASES;`I receive the error:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SHOW DATABASES privilege(s) for this operation
```

I have checked the user privileges with `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;` and seems I have all:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'tec'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ' *F0AAB5B469***16C3449'

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `tec`.* TO 'tec'@'%'
```

what can be the reason?

```
Server version: 10.0.32-MariaDB-0+deb8u1 (Debian)
```

Comment: MariaDB version?.

Comment: Server version: 10.0.32-MariaDB-0+deb8u1 (Debian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```bsh
$ mysql -u tec -p
Enter password:
```

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT VERSION(), CURRENT_USER();
+-----------------+----------------+
| VERSION()       | CURRENT_USER() |
+-----------------+----------------+
| 10.0.33-MariaDB | tec@%          |
+-----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for tec@%                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'tec'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F0AAB5B469***16C3449' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `tec`.* TO 'tec'@'%'                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| tec                |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

Check [`skip_show_database`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#skip_show_database) server system variable.

**my.cnf**

```bsh
...

[mysqld]
...
skip_show_database
...
```

```bsh
$ mysql -u tec -p
Enter password:
```

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT VERSION(), CURRENT_USER();
+-----------------+----------------+
| VERSION()       | CURRENT_USER() |
+-----------------+----------------+
| 10.0.33-MariaDB | tec@%          |
+-----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for tec@%                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'tec'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F0AAB5B469***16C3449' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `tec`.* TO 'tec'@'%'                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW DATABASES;
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SHOW DATABASES privilege(s) for this operation
```

**UPDATE 2**

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES
    -> WHERE `Variable_name` = 'skip_show_database';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| skip_show_database | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @stefano-maglione: Updated answer.

Comment: @stefano-maglione: `If set to 1 (ON), (0 (OFF) is the default), only users with the SHOW DATABASES privilege can use the SHOW DATABASES statement to see all database names.`, see [skip_show_database](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#skip_show_database).

Comment: Ok, but I have SHOW DATABASES privilege I think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158522/discussion-between-stefano-maglione-and-wchiquito).

Comment: @stefano-maglione: `tec` user has [Database Privilege](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/grant/#database-privileges), `SHOW DATABASES` is a [Global Privilege](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/grant/#global-privileges).

Comment: How can I set this Global privilege? I tried with SET GLOBAL skip_show_database='OFF'; but it says it is only read variable

Comment: @stefano-maglione: You must modify your MariaDB configuration file (my.cnf) and restart MariaDB.